# Visual Studio: How to test (in code / static_assert) if a compiler option is enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-assert, compiler-options

I would like to check, in the code, if certain options where set at compile time.

Specifically, I have implemented some exception handling and would like to use a static_assert to be sure the /EHa option was set in the Visual Studio compiler.  (I am using 2017 and 2019 with C++Latest enabled)

My solution has 54 projects each of which have 4 configs....   Easy to miss one.
Or...  I might want the code to be different if the option is not set....

many thanks

Comment: Back in the day, I'd compile my code like `cl /EHa /O3 -DCL_OPTS="/EHa /O3" foo.cpp` and then I could use the CL_OPTS macro in my code.  There may be a CL.EXE way that I'm unaware of, but this was the expedient way I did it.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160

Comment: Searching 54 `.vcxproj` files should be a light task for any decent text editor. But it would make more sense to put the common build options into a shared `.props` file.

Comment: @Eljay   Thanks

certainly an option.

Comment: @Richard-Critten   Thanks.

_CPPUNWIND is the only that looks hopeful, but it is defined (as 1) even when other /EH options are used

Answer (score 1):

As I played with the options, I did find that the compiler is already giving a warning for this : `warning C4535: calling _set_se_translator() requires /EHa`

I looked to see if that was an attribute or decorator on the function in the VS headers so I could transplant it directly in my code, but could not find anything.

So far, I have thus settled on adding a comment in the code for other developers to see when the warning is given.

```
// Save & Restore the Structured Exception Handler
// Set our own handler during the call
class Scoped_SE_Translator
{
private:
    const _se_translator_function old_SE_translator;
public:
    Scoped_SE_Translator() = delete;
    Scoped_SE_Translator(_se_translator_function new_SE_translator) noexcept :  // NOTE: Compiler option /EHa is required  ("Enable C++ Exception" = "Yes with SEH Exceptions")
        old_SE_translator{_set_se_translator(new_SE_translator)} { }
    ~Scoped_SE_Translator() noexcept { _set_se_translator(old_SE_translator); }
};
```

I also set up project defaults in my existing solution.props file:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <ExceptionHandling>Async</ExceptionHandling>
      <FloatingPointExceptions>true</FloatingPointExceptions>
      <TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors>4535;%(TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors)</TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

However, that depends on developers adding a line in new vcxproj files:

`<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)SolutionSettings.props" />`

I am not sure if there is a more 'forceful' way to ensure new projects have the 'correct' defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use [Predefined macros(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160).

> _CPPUNWIND: Defined as 1 if one or more of the /GX (Enable Exception Handling), /clr (Common Language Runtime Compilation), or [/EH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160)
> (Exception Handling Model) compiler options are set. Otherwise,
> undefined.

Also, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [To set this compiler option programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.exceptionhandling?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).

Besides, you could also use code to determine whether /EHa is enabled. For example:

```
inline bool CodeHasEHaSwitch()
{
    bool dtorCalled = false;

    struct CCheckEHaSwitch
    {
        CCheckEHaSwitch( bool& dtorCalled) : dtorCalled( dtorCalled ) {}
        ~CCheckEHaSwitch() {  dtorCalled = true; }
        bool& dtorCalled;

        static void Win32ExceptionTranslator( unsigned int nExceptionCode,
        EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pExceptionInfo )
        {  throw nExceptionCode; }
    };

    _se_translator_function pfnPrevSeTranslator =
        _set_se_translator( CCheckEHaSwitch::Win32ExceptionTranslator );
    try
    {
        CCheckEHaSwitch test( dtorCalled );

        *((int*)0) = 0;  // generate access violation
    }
    catch (unsigned int)
    {
    }

    _set_se_translator( pfnPrevSeTranslator );

    return dtorCalled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barrnet-Chou -- great function in concept, but you won't know the answer until you run the code :-)

I've checked the Predefines, but _CPPUNWIND is defined as 1 even for other /EH? options.